# Make the display url of a web site different than the actual url for bookmarking purposes

Tags: url, bookmarks

Is it possible to display a different url than the actual url for bookmarking purposes?

Here's why, web site a.com is live and being use for administrative purposes that have not been added to the new site. So when a user visits a.com, they are redirected to a_new.com. But a_new.com is temporary and will eventually become a.com so I need users to be able to to bookmark a.com even though they are at a_new.com.

Makes sense?
Cool,
Thanks,

W

Answer (score 1):

NO

And this is a good thing (though it won't help you)

For example if user visits www.goodsite.com

And goodsite is a good site but vulnerable to script injection. So an evil hacker changes the bookmarking property of goodsite.com to evilsite.com

Next user who bookmarks the site is in for  a surprise.

The best thing to do I think would be when the new domain comes up set up a redirect on the pages of the temporary domain